# $x^2-Dy^2=1$ has integer solution, does $x^2-Dy^2=-1$ also have?

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

> If I know that $x^2-Dy^2=1$ has integer solutions, what are the conditions that $x^2-Dy^2=-1$ has also integer solutions ?

For example $x^2-141y^2=1$ has a solution $(95,8)$ but for $x^2-141y^2=-1$ there doesn't exist a solution in integers.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_negative_Pell_equation

Comment: See also problem 11 here: http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=618&lmm=0

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry but from the link, it should be solvable (...In fact, if and only if the period length of the continued fraction for $\sqrt{n}$ is odd, then $x^2-ny^2 = -1$ is solvable...) and $\sqrt{141}=[11,\overline{1,6,22}]$, am I wrong ?

Comment: $$\sqrt{141}=[1,\overline{1,6,1,22}]$$

Answer (score 2):

The two questions are unrelated.  The first is called [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_smallest_solution_of_Pell_equations), and has solutions exactly when $D$ is not a square (apart from the trivial solution $x=1$, $y=0$).

The latter is called [the negative Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_negative_Pell_equation).  It is the subject of ongoing study, some results of which may be found in that link. For example, if some prime $p|D$, and $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then there is no solution for $D$. (Note: this explains $D=141=3\times 47$).  A list of those $D$ for which this is solvable can be found on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A031396).

Answer (score 2):

If your $D$ is a prime with $D \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ then there is a solution in integers to $x^2 - D y^2 = -1.$ There is a short and simple proof in Mordell's book. Of course, there is a solution to $x^2 - 2 y^2 = -1.$

If $D$ is divisible by $4$ or by any prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$ there is no solution.

Finally, if all prime factors of $D$ are either $2$ or $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ but $D$ is composite (not a perfect square) there might or might not be integer solutions to $x^2 - D y^2 = -1.$

We have $8^2 - 65 = -1,$ also $378^2 - 85 * 41^2 = -1.$

However, no such luck for $D$ equal to $34 = 2 \cdot 17,$ or $205 = 5 \cdot 41,$ or $221 = 13 \cdot 17.$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell 34


0  form   1 10 -9   delta  -1
1  form   -9 8 2   delta  4
2  form   2 8 -9   delta  -1
3  form   -9 10 1   delta  10
4  form   1 10 -9

 disc   136
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
5  54
6  65


 Pell automorph 
35  204
6  35

Pell unit 
35^2 - 34 * 6^2 = 1 


34      2 *  17

=========================================


jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell 205


0  form   1 28 -9   delta  -3
1  form   -9 26 4   delta  6
2  form   4 22 -21   delta  -1
3  form   -21 20 5   delta  4
4  form   5 20 -21   delta  -1
5  form   -21 22 4   delta  6
6  form   4 26 -9   delta  -3
7  form   -9 28 1   delta  28
8  form   1 28 -9

 disc   820
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
881  24948
2772  78497


 Pell automorph 
39689  568260
2772  39689

Pell unit 
39689^2 - 205 * 2772^2 = 1 

=========================================

  4 PRIMITIVE 
43^2 - 205 * 3^2 = 4 

=========================================

205      5 *  41

=========================================


jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./Pell 221


0  form   1 28 -25   delta  -1
1  form   -25 22 4   delta  6
2  form   4 26 -13   delta  -2
3  form   -13 26 4   delta  6
4  form   4 22 -25   delta  -1
5  form   -25 28 1   delta  28
6  form   1 28 -25

 disc   884
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
97  2800
112  3233


 Pell automorph 
1665  24752
112  1665

Pell unit 
1665^2 - 221 * 112^2 = 1 

=========================================

  4 PRIMITIVE 
15^2 - 221 * 1^2 = 4 

=========================================

221      13 *  17


=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

................